# why does my code say that urllib.request has no attribute get url()?

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I'm trying to use the urllib.request module in python 3.6 and I need to know if the page has been redirected but my program keeps throwing up an error that urllib.request.geturl() is not an attribute of urllib.request even though I have checked  with the python module index and looked on urllib and geturl() is definitely defined there.

This is the code:

```
req = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.tumblr.com/dashboard")
resp = urllib.request.geturl(req)

url = resp.read()
print(url)
```

Any idea why this is not working? (I am expecting the url to be redirected to either www.tumblr.com/login or www.tumblr.com/register as it is not logged in)

Comment: No it isn't: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.geturl. If you read the docs, they say that *the object `urlopen` returns* has that method, but it doesn't give you a response.

Comment: @jonrsharpe how do I use this function correctly then in this context?

Comment: No worries, added an if statement (if req.geturl() == "www.......": and this worked